# My viewDidAppear not called in view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

It turns out that what I want to do is that when I come from a 3d shortcut, forcing the `UITabBarController` to choose an index, if I do this in the tab bar `viewDidAppear()` the problem is that the `viewDidAppear()` of my main `UIViewController` Embedded is not called, if I click again on the tab bar item then already if it is called. With the rest of the drivers does not happen, I understand why it is not the one that is first in the list of items in the `UITabBarController`.

Tab bar controller: (Here it comes)

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if goTasks {
        self.selectedIndex = 0
    } else if goTodo {
        self.selectedIndex = 2
    } else if goProjects {
        self.selectedIndex = 3
    } else if goSearch {
        self.selectedIndex = 0
    }

}
```

My first `UIViewController`:
(Not called this method)

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print("Entry")
}
```

Is the problem `override` the methods? Any solution?

Comment: Do you have any class for UITabBarController ?

Comment: super.viewDidAppear(animated) should be the very first line ;) inside your method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your UITabBarController class **viewDidAppear func** , call it's super class, like this

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if goTasks {
            self.selectedIndex = 0
        } else if goTodo {
            self.selectedIndex = 2
        } else if goProjects {
            self.selectedIndex = 3
        } else if goSearch {
            self.selectedIndex = 0
        }

    }
```

After that, your first viewcontroller will call this method.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    print("Entry")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to call function from super:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated) // here what i ment

    if goTasks {
        self.selectedIndex = 0
    } else if goTodo {
        self.selectedIndex = 2
    } else if goProjects {
        self.selectedIndex = 3
    } else if goSearch {
        self.selectedIndex = 0
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if goTasks {
        self.selectedIndex = 0
    } else if goTodo {
        self.selectedIndex = 2
    } else if goProjects {
        self.selectedIndex = 3
    } else if goSearch {
        self.selectedIndex = 0
    }
}
```

You need to add super.viewDidAppear(animated), hope its word now

Answer (score 0):

What mistake I was doing, i placed `super.viewDidAppear(true)` inside my `viewWillAppear` appear block.